# Spin^c structures on manifolds with almost complex structure

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, differential-topology, spin-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth even-dimensional manifold.

1. Is it true that for each almost-complex structure $J$ on $M$ there exists a canonical spin$^c$ structure $S_J$ associated to $J$ ? 
   (I've read this somewhere but I didn't see the actual construction).

Is there a way to caracterize that spin$^c$ structure ? (What I mean by that is : is there a theorem of the form : $S_J$ is the unique spin$^c$ structure on $M$ satisfying [*a property of compability with $J$*]).

2. Suppose $M$ admits an almost-complex structure. Does every spin$^c$ structure comes from an almost-complex structure on $M$ (i.e. is it true that every spin$^c$ structure is equal to a $S_J$ for an almost-complex structure $J$ ?). 
   (If not : what happens if we restrict to parallelizable open 4-manifolds ?).
3. Same question as <strike>1.</strike> **2.** but for spin (and not just spin$^c$) structures. **EDIT** (to clarifiy this question) : Does every spin structure on $M$ <strike>comes from</strike> *has an associated* spin^c structure that is associated to an almost-complex structure $J$ on $M$ ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assume that $M$ is oriented throughout. Recall that $M$ has a $\text{Spin}^c$ structure iff the third integral Stiefel-Whitney class $\beta w_2 = W_3 \in H^3(M, \mathbb{Z})$ is trivial. Actually more is true: $\text{Spin}^c$ structures on $M$ are in bijection with trivializations of $W_3$, which are a torsor over $H^2(M, \mathbb{Z})$. So we get a functorial way to associate a $\text{Spin}^c$ structure to an almost complex structure for every choice of nullhomotopy of the composite map

$$BU(n) \to BSO(2n) \xrightarrow{W_3} B^3 \mathbb{Z}.$$

Isomorphism classes of nullhomotopies are a torsor over $H^2(BU(n), \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$. I don't know in what sense there's a canonical one, but once you pick one you don't have to make any further choices, and in particular you don't have to make any further choices involving $M$. (**Edit #2:** But see below.)

As for almost complex structures, there is a canonical fiber bundle

$$SO(2n)/U(n) \to BU(n) \to BSO(2n)$$

and almost complex structures on $M$ correspond to sections of the pullback of this bundle along the classifying map $M \to BSO(2n)$ of the tangent bundle. This admits a map of bundles to the corresponding bundle

$$B^2 \mathbb{Z} \to B \text{Spin}^c(2n) \to BSO(2n)$$

describing $\text{Spin}^c$ structures. The map $SO(2n)/U(n) \to B^2 \mathbb{Z}$ describes a canonical line bundle on the space of linear complex structures on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$, namely the complex determinant bundle.

This tells us that we already can't expect all $\text{Spin}^c$ structures to come from almost complex structures when $n = 1$: here $SO(2)/U(1)$ is contractible, so there is in a very strong sense a unique almost complex structure on an oriented surface, but $\text{Spin}^c$ structures are a torsor over $H^2(-, \mathbb{Z})$, which can be nontrivial, e.g. on an oriented closed surface.

**Edit #2:** I believe that there is in fact a distinguished nullhomotopy of the composite map $BU(n) \xrightarrow{W_3} B^3 \mathbb{Z}$, as follows.

We now need the additional assumption that $M$ is Riemannian (although the choice of Riemannian metric won't matter). Then a conceptual description of $W_3 \in H^3(M, \mathbb{Z})$ is that it classifies the bundle of complex Clifford algebras $\text{Cliff}(T_x(M)) \otimes \mathbb{C}$ up to Morita equivalence. Trivializations of this bundle up to Morita equivalence correspond to Clifford module bundles with fiber the unique irreducible representation of $\text{Cliff}(2n) \otimes \mathbb{C}$ (complex spinor bundles).

If $M$ has an almost complex structure, then a distinguished complex spinor bundle can be constructed out of the complex exterior algebra of the tangent bundle. See Exercise 2.1.37 in Freed's [Geometry of Dirac Operators](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/dafr/DiracNotes.pdf) for details. The torsor structure over $H^2(M, \mathbb{Z})$ comes from tensoring this bundle with complex line bundles on $M$, and the action of $H^2(BU(n), \mathbb{Z})$ comes from tensoring this bundle with powers of the canonical bundle. It's possible one might want to do this with a particular power; I'm not sure what's going on here exactly, but see Exercise 2.1.54 in Freed.

**Edit #3:** Now that the third question has been clarified, I don't know the answer off the top of my head. In the case of closed oriented surfaces we know that there's a $\mathbb{Z}$'s worth of $\text{Spin}^c$ structures. The unique almost complex structure gives rise to one, and the $2^{2g}$ spin structures also give rise to one (not depending on the spin structure, basically because the Bockstein homomorphism $H^1(M, \mathbb{Z}_2) \to H^2(M, \mathbb{Z})$ is zero in this case). But I don't know if they're the same one; they might differ by a power of the canonical bundle or something (or not, depending on your convention for trivializing $W_3$ as above). In summary,

1. Yes, more or less,
2. No, and
3. I don't know, but I would guess no.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For 1., the article https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/spin%5Ec+structure refers to a "canonical" spin^c structure, but I can't say I understand really. Do you see in there a way to choose a special class of nullhomotopy of the composite map ?

Comment: For 3. I can't see how this answers the question, if M has no spin structure, then the answer to "Does every spin structure on M, etc." is yes.

Comment: @Michael: I think the nLab is ignoring the subtlety I point out above: that although it's true that the pullback of $W_3$ to $BU(n)$ is nullhomotopic, you need to choose a nullhomotopy, and there's more than one. However, again as pointed out above, once you make this choice there are no further choices. For 3 I interpreted the question to be "does every almost complex structure give rise to a canonical spin structure" and the answer is no. If the question you intended to ask is "does every spin structure give rise to a canonical $\text{Spin}^c$ structure" then you should clarify the wording.

Comment: Thank you, so I guess the answer to 1. is NO. But it is YES, up to a nullhomotopy choice. I re-worded question 3.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan What you said for $n=1$ isn't true. There can exist many almost complex structures (they're all integrable), but a unique one determined by a conformal structure.

Comment: @Chris: it depends on what your definition of an equivalence of almost complex structures is. With the (homotopy-theoretic) definition I have in mind, almost complex structures correspond to lifts-up-to-homotopy of the classifying map of the tangent bundle to $BU(n)$, up to homotopy. When $n = 1$ the space of such lifts from $BSO(2)$ is contractible.

Answer (score 8):

A $\text{Spin}^c$ structure is equivalent to (a homotopy class of) an almost complex structure on the 2-skeleton of a manifold which extends to the 3-skeleton (except for a surface or when the fiber dimension is odd, where we first need to stabilize the tangent bundle). So in the case of 4-manifolds without 4-handles (in particular 4-manifolds with non-empty boundary) there is a canonical one to one correspondence between $\text{Spin}^c$ structures and almost complex structures. The original reference for this result is Gompf's *[Spin^c structures and homotopy equivalences](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9705218)* (https://doi.org/10.2140/gt.1997.1.41), but there is a more expository version available in *[Surgery on Contact 3-Manifolds and Stein Surfaces](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-662-10167-4)* by Ozbagci and Stipsicz.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, this answers positively 1 and 2, in the case of 4-manifolds without 3-handles. I was not able to directly see this result in the references you mentioned (I guess it's a direct consequence, but I'm not familiar enough with this subject to see that as trivial). So just so that I understand a little bit better, why having no 3-handles implies that there is a canonical bijection between Spin^c structures and almost-complex structures?

Comment: @Michael I meant without 4-handles. In this case extending an almost complex structure to the 3-skeleton is the same as extending it to $M$.

Comment: I have to admit I have no intuitive feeling (beyond the definition) as what means geometrically to not have a 4-handle for a 4-manifold. Why is it that extending to the 3-skeleton is the same as extending to M ? Is it because a 4-manifold without 4 handle is equal to its 3 skeleton ?